# How to convert List of Lists to single List using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to convert following code using stream without using for each loop.

1. getAllSubjects() returns all List and each Subject has `List<Topic>`.  all List should be combined as `List<Topic>`.
2. Needs to get `Map<id,topicName>`   from `List<Topic>`

**Object Model:**

```
Subject
  id,....
  List<Topic>
Topic
  id,name

public Map<String, String> getSubjectIdAndName(final String subjectId) {

    List<Subject> list = getAllSubjects(); // api method returns all subjects
    //NEEDS TO IMPROVE CODE USING STREAMS
    list = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getId().equals(subjectId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Topic> topicList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Subject s : list) {
        List<Topic> tlist = s.getTopics();
        topicList.addAll(tlist);
    }
    return topicList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Topic::getId, Topic::getName));

}
```

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Just remove these intermediate collections into `List`s, then, study [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and you’re done. In other words, `return getAllSubjects() .stream() .filter(e -> e.getId().equals(subjectId)) .flatMap(s -> s.getTopics().stream()) .collect(Collectors.toMap(Topic::getId, Topic::getName));`

Comment: @Holger seems like the answer rather than a comment. ;)

Comment: Thank you @Holger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `flatMap` here, to not stream again. Just notice that this `toMap` assumes that there will be no duplicate keys (or nulls)

```
list.stream()
    .filter(e -> subjectId.equals(e.getId()))
    .flatMap(subject -> subject.getTopics().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Topic::getId, Topic::getName));
```